# Find out if file has been modified within the last 2 minutes

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

In a bash script I want to check if a file has been changed within the last 2 minutes.

I already found out that I can access the date of the last modification with `stat file.ext -c %y`. How can I check if this date is older than two minutes?

Answer (score 32):

Complete script to do what you're after:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Input file
FILE=/tmp/test.txt
# How many seconds before file is deemed "older"
OLDTIME=120
# Get current and file times
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
FILETIME=$(stat $FILE -c %Y)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)

# Check if file older
if [ $TIMEDIFF -gt $OLDTIME ]; then
   echo "File is older, do stuff here"
fi
```

If you're on `macOS`, use `stat -t %s -f %m $FILE` for `FILETIME`, as in a comment by Alcanzar.

Comment: In case anyone else finds this, on a mac, for FILETIME use `stat -t %s -f %m $FILENAME`

Comment: Just a note: expr has a strange behaviour that ends with status code 1 if the arithmetic result is 0. TIMEDIFF=$((CURTIME - FILETIME)) was a better choice for my use-case.

Answer (score 31):

I think this would be helpful,

```
find . -mmin -2 -type f -print
```

also,

```
find / -fstype local -mmin -2
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's an even simpler version that uses shell math over expr:

SECONDS (for idea)

```
echo $(( $(date +%s) - $(stat file.txt  -c %Y) ))
```

MINUTES (for answer)

```
echo $(( ($(date +%s) - $(stat file.txt  -c %Y)) / 60 ))
```

HOURS

```
echo $(( ($(date +%s) - $(stat file.txt  -c %Y)) / 3600 ))
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I would do it: (I would use a proper temp file)

```
touch -d"-2min" .tmp
[ "$file" -nt .tmp ] && echo "file is less than 2 minutes old"
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the cleanest most sensible way to do this!

Answer (score 10):

I solved the problem this way: get the current date and last modified date of the file (both in unix timestamp format). Subtract the modified date from the current date and divide the result by 60 (to convert it to minutes).

```
expr $(expr $(date +%s) - $(stat mail1.txt -c %Y)) / 60
```

Maybe this is not the cleanest solution, but it works great.

Answer (score 3):

For those who like 1-liners once in a while:

```bash
test $(stat -c %Y -- "$FILE") -gt $(($EPOCHSECONDS - 120))
```

This solution is also safe with any kind of file name, including if it contains `` %!"`' () ``

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that will test if a file is older than X seconds. It doesn't use `stat`, which has platform-specific syntax, or `find` which doesn't have granularity finer than 1 minute.

```
interval_in_seconds=10
filetime=$(date -r "$filepath" +"%s")
now=$(date +"%s")
timediff=$(expr $now - $filetime)
if [ $timediff -ge $interval_in_seconds ]; then
  echo ""
fi
```