# Nginx Reload Configuration Best Practice

Tags: nginx

Currently setting up a nginx reverse-proxy load-balancing a wide variety of domain names.

nginx configuration files are programatically generated and might change very often (ie add or delete http/https servers)

I am using:

```
nginx -s reload
```

To tell nginx to re-read the configuration.

the main nginx.conf file contain an include of all the generated configuration files as such:

```
http {
  include /volumes/config/*/domain.conf;
}
```

Included configuration file might look like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /404.html /404.htm =404;
    root /volumes/sites/mydomain;
  }
}
```

**My question:**

Is it healthy or considered harmfull to run:

```
nginx -s reload
```

multiple times per minutes to notify nginx to take into account modifications on the configuration?
What kind of performance hit would that imply ?

EDIT: **I'd like to reformulate the question: How can we make it possible to dynamically change the configuration of nginx very often without a big perfomance hit ?**

Answer (score 5):

I would use `inotifywatch` with a timeout on the directory containing the generated conf files and reload `nginx` only if something was modified/created/deleted in said directory during that time:

> -t , --timeout 
>  Listen only for the specified amount of seconds.  If not specified, inotifywatch will gather
>   statistics until receiving an interrupt signal by (for example)
>   pressing CONTROL-C at the console.

```
while true; do
    if [[ "$(inotifywatch -e modify,create,delete -t 30 /volumes/config/ 2>&1)" =~ filename ]]; then
        service nginx reload;
    fi;
done
```

This way you set up a minimum timer after which the reloads will take place *and* you don't lose any watches between calls to `inotifywait`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it still might cause nginx to reload multiple times a minute if the configuration does really get updated that often, do we know what kind of performance hit we are looking at ?

Comment: You can change the timeout to 60s or whatever you deem acceptable and it will reload at most once every timer, only if configs changed during that time. Do you really change configs that often? There shouldn't be that big of a hit.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the problem from the wrong point of view, but i do need to be able to change the nginx configuration very very often (without hurting the runtime performance) ideally 10x+ per minute

Comment: @Crappy are you sure that's the only way to handle it? i often send lots of traffic to a map script which uses cached database queries to figure out what to do dynamically instead

Answer (score 2):

If you

1. Use a script similar to what's [provided in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341234/578023), let's call it `check_nginx_confs.sh`
2. Change your ExecStart directive in nginx.service so `/etc/nginx/` is `/dev/shm/nginx/`
3. Add a script to `/etc/init.d/` to copy conf files to your temp dir ------------------------
   `mkdir /dev/shm/nginx && cp /etc/nginx/* /dev/shm/nginx`
4. Use rsync (or other sync tool) to sync `/dev/shm/nginx` back to `/etc/nginx`; so you dont lose config files created in `/dev/shm/nginx` on reboot. Or simply make both locations in-app, for atomic checks as desired
5. Set a cronjob to run `check_nginx_confs.sh` as often as files 'turn old' in `check_nginx_confs.sh`, so you know if a change happened within the last time window but only check once
6. Only `systemctl reload ngnix` if `check_nginx_confs.sh` finds a new file, once per time period defined by $OLDTIME
7. Rest

Now nginx will load those configs much, much faster; from RAM. It will only reload once every $OLDTIME seconds and only if it needs to. Beyond just routing requests to a dynamic handler of your own; this is probably the fastest you get nginx to reload frequently

It's a good idea to reserve a certain disk quota to the temp directory you use, to ensure you don't run out of memory. There are various ways of accomplishing that. You can also add a symlink to an empty, on-disk directory in case you have to spill over but that'd be a lot of confs

Script from other answer:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Input file
TESTDIR=/dev/shm/nginx
# How many seconds before dir is deemed "older"
OLDTIME=75 
#add a little grace period, optional
# Get current and file times
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
FILETIME=$(date -r $TESTDIR +%s)
TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)

# Check if dir updated in last 120 seconds
if [ $OLDTIME -gt $TIMEDIFF ]; then
   systemctl nginx reload
fi

# Run me every 1 minute with cron
```

Optionally; if you're feeling up to it you can put the copy and sync commands in `nginx.service`'s ExecStart with some && magic so they always happen together. You can also && a sort of 'destructor function' which does a final sync and frees `/dev/shm/nginx` on ExecStop. This would replace step (3) and (4)

Alternative to cron; you can have a script running a loop in the background with a wait duration. If you do this, you can pass LastUpdateTime back and forth between the two scripts for greater accuracy as LastUpdateTime+GracePeriod is more reliable. With this, I would still use cron to periodically make sure the loop is still running

For reference, on my CentOS 7 images, nginx.service is at 
`/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reloading nginx several times a minute I would suggest to watch the config file and execute the reload only when the changes are  saved; you can use [inotifywait](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) (available through the `inotify-tools` package) with the following command:

`while inotifywait -e close_write /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; do service nginx reload; done`

Comment: That's the best solution i could think of too, but what if the configuration do indeed needs to changes multiple times a minute ?

Comment: `close_wait` doesn't catch `delete` events, not does it imply the file was written to. close_write => "A  watched  file  or  a file within a watched directory was closed, after being opened in writeable mode.  This does not necessarily imply the file was written to."