# Or statement in bash with grep

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am writing a bash script that cycles through a list of files and does something either when the file contains a certain word, or the file was created within the [last X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337961/find-out-if-file-has-been-modified-within-the-last-2-minutes). The script works fine with only the first requirement

```
if grep -q $error $f; then
```

, but I don't know how to include the "or" statement.

I have tried the following ( I am new to bash so I tried things that may not even make sense ).

```
FILES=logdir/*.out
OLDTIME=86400
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
error='exit'
for f in $FILES
do
    FILETIME=$(stat $f -c %Y)
    TIMEDIFF=$(expr $CURTIME - $FILETIME)
    if [[ grep -q $error $f ]] || [[$OLDTIME -gt $TIMEDIFF ]] ; then
```

or

```
if [[ grep -q $error $f || $OLDTIME -gt $TIMEDIFF ]] ; then
```

gives me

```
./script.sh: line 12: conditional binary operator expected
./script.sh: line 12: syntax error near `-q'
```

and

```
if [ grep -q $error $f ] || [ $OLDTIME -gt $TIMEDIFF ] ; then
```

gives me

```
./script.sh: line 12: [: too many arguments
./script.sh: line 12: [: 1: unary operator expected
```

How can I have both conditions in the if statement?

Comment: You are making the common mistake of assuming that `[` or `[[` is part of the `if` statement's syntax. It's not; you simply say `if grep whatever || [ "$OLDTIME" -gt "$TIMEDIFF" ]; then ...` (though ideally you should use lower case for your private variables).

Answer (score 3):

It's easier than you think :-)

```sh
if /bin/true || /bin/false; then echo hi; fi
```

prints `hi`

```sh
if /bin/false || /bin/false; then echo hi; fi
```

prints nothing.

In other words, you don't need the `[` or `[[` operators. Just execute the commands to return their status and use `||` to "or" them.

Comment: I think you miss a `then` token in both statements after the condition evaluation ;)

Comment: agreed, `fi unexepected` ;-)

Comment: You're right -- I tested only in zsh. Fixed now.