# modifying atime to check if file has been modified within last 24 hours

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/cc/uvreadings

while true
do
   ATIME=`stat -c %Z /home/pi/cc/uvreadings/uvreadings.log`

   if [[ "$ATIME" < "$LTIME" ]]
   then
       echo "log file not updated for +24 hours"
   else
       echo "log file WAS updated in last +24 hours"
   fi

   sleep 10
done
```

I am trying to check if a file has been modified in the last 24 hours by comparing atime to Ltime

atime will always be less than ltime

so can i modify the statement

```
if [[ "$ATIME" < "$LTIME" ]]
```

to

```
if [[ "$ATIME +1 day" < "$LTIME" ]]`
```

of is the a better way to achieve this

thanks for any advice

Comment: What's `ltime` meant to be?  And you may want to work on your formatting ...

Comment: ltime is the local time on the raspberry pi

Comment: Do the pointers here help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337961/find-out-if-file-has-been-modified-within-the-last-2-minutes

Comment: Does `find` exist on pi?  Option `-mtime` would do that.

Comment: yes the link displayed above has the answer thank you for the information

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are (at least) [three different timestamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/timestamp-modification-time-and-created-time-of-a-file) on a file, and you seem to have them mixed up.  You talk about atime, the `%Z` option instead gives you ctime, and it sounds like what you want is actually mtime: the time at which the file's contents last changed.  You can get mtime with `stat -c %Y`.

To see if it was less than one day ago, you can indeed add one day to it; but the time is in seconds, so you need to add `24*60*60` seconds.  The easiest way to do that is probably with [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html).  It could look something like this:

```
if [[ $((MTIME + (24 * 60 * 60))) > $LTIME ]] # modified in the last day
```

I assume you wrote code to get the current time and store it in `LTIME`, even though you didn't show that code in your question.  It has to go inside the loop, of course.  One way to do that would be

```
LTIME=`date +%s`
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that explanation very helpful and informative, have it running now with the help of all the above comments thanks again